# Fallo en fecha_creacion Illegal string offset Warning PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
'Fecha: ' . date('d-m-y', strtotime($lnk_detalles_entrada
['fecha_creacion'])) . '.' .(
$incidencias_activas > 1 ? ' Y ' . (
$incidencias_activas - 1) . ' más.' : '')
```

No veo donde esta está el fallo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo que quiero conseguir es visualizar ese triangulo y que al pasar el ratón por encima me muestre si hay incidencias, que estas se sacan de otro php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
el codigo completo que he añadido es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ahora me sale esto, al pasar el ratón por encima se muestra el triangulo pero me sale este mensaje.

Comment: No pareces estar incluyendo la parte del código que está fallando. Ten en cuenta que tu código muestra `fecha_creacion` pero el error de la imagen habla de `fecha_de_creacion`. Lo más probable es que hayas puesto mal el nombre en la vista y deba ir `fecha_creacion` en lugar de `fecha_de_creacion` dentro de la línea 142 del archivo views\admin\inicio.php, pero es una mera especulación. Lo mejor será que edites la pregunta con la función que carga la vista `inicio.php` y que también incluyas ésta.

Comment: El error que estás sufriendo es debido a que `$lnk_detalles_entrada` es una cadena de caracteres (fíjate que previamente lo usas para el atributo `href` del enlace), por lo que solo puedes usar el operador `[]` con índices numéricos para acceder a cada uno de los caracteres que la componen, por lo que el índice `['fecha_creacion']` es erróneo. Comprueba el contenido y tipo de esa variable para solucionar tu problema. Ninguna de las capturas de pantalla tiene el suficiente código para indicarte cuál es la variante correcta que deberías usar ahí, aunque tiene pinta de ser `$entrada`.

Comment: ok. lo estoy rehaciendo poco a poco. gracias